# Creating a GUI with Tkinter of Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written the following code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Power Method")

labeltext1 = StringVar()  
labeltext2 = StringVar()
labeltext1.set('Parameters') # Set start value
labeltext2.set('Epsilon')

label1 = Label (root, textvariable = labeltext1, height = 4)
label1.pack()
Entry(root, textvariable = labeltext1). pack()
label2 = Label (root, textvariable = labeltext2)
label2.pack()
Entry(root, textvariable = labeltext2). pack()

checkBox1 = Checkbutton(root, text = "NumPy")
checkBox1.pack()
checkBox2 = Checkbutton(root, text = "Not NumPy")
checkBox2.pack() 

Button(root, text = "Exit").pack(side = RIGHT)
Button(root, text = "Compute").pack(side = RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

This code, when run, creates a window that contains Parameters, Epsilon as two places that you could enter value and NumPy and Not NumPy as checkboxes and finally a compute and exit button.

I am trying to format the code, in a way that Parameters and Epsilon appear on the left of the window, Numpy and Not Numpy infront of them on the right and Compute and Exit stay in their current positions.

Any help regarding the formatting would be appreciated.

Comment: Its good practice to use the GUI with Object oriented programming methods. i tried your program and it dsnt do anything, no tkinter box opened up. Did you try in for yourself?

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed, I have tried it myself several times and did it again as you asked, it opens the window with descriptions in my comment.

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this problem? Have you read the documentation on `grid` and `pack`? Is there something about those commands you don't understand?

Comment: @user1759438 my bad. I copy pasted your code and missed `root.mainloop()`. Whenever Ive played with tKinter, ive used it in an Object Oriented manner. The best way to place the `entry` and `check` boxes are by using the `.grid()`. I allows you to give `width` , `height` , `columspam` etc along with `sticky direction` which use `N,S,E or W` to help you place your labels or buttons in the right place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright you need to google `.grid()` and `.pack()` and `.place()` for tkinter to learn more about what each is good for. For your case you could use any of them, but `.grid()` is probably the best and easiest for you to use.

To do this you must change `.pack()` to `.grid()` everywhere you have it, then you should use the `row` and `column` options to put your widgets where you want them. E.G.

```
label1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
label2.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
```

this will put `label2` on the right side of `label1`. The way `.grid()` works is that the columns are as wide as the largest (widest) widget in that column, same applies for rows.

if you need anything else just ask, but please do look at the documentations as Bryan said.

Comment: Thank you! I have started reading the documentations on .pack() and .grid() and it is very helpful. Sorry for posting the question before studying the documents thoroughly.